# Cannot run Tensorflow GPU on Docker (although it seems to be installed outside of it)

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Here is my situation

I downloaded the tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu image. In order to run it, I run the following command to start the docker image:

```
docker run -it --rm \
--ipc=host \
  --gpus all \
  --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
  --volume="$(pwd)/://mydir:rw" \
  --workdir="/mydir/" \
  tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu bash -c 'bash'
```

However, whenever I run the following Python commands:

```
>> import tensorflow as tf
>> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Here is the output I have (inside the Docker):

```
2023-06-26 13:10:46.768093: E 

tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:266] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW
2023-06-26 13:10:46.768177: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:168] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: 466cc7912253
2023-06-26 13:10:46.768189: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:175] hostname: 466cc7912253
2023-06-26 13:10:46.768314: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:199] libcuda reported version is: NOT_FOUND: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
2023-06-26 13:10:46.768355: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:203] kernel reported version is: 515.65.1
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Here is what I have outside and INSIDE docker:

```
## nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P0    58W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P0    59W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P0    60W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   32C    P0    59W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:88:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   26C    P0    58W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   28C    P0    57W / 250W |      0MiB / 11264MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also can see that there is a CUDA version installed:

```
## nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0
```

So what can I do to make my docker image see where is my CUDA and make my code run in the GPU?

Comment: Have you followed the nvidia docker [installation process](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html) ? Does the following command work: `docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.6.2-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi` ?

Comment: @Lescurel thank you so much for your prompt response. I could run your command successfully and it showed me that I have 5 GPUs available. Was I running the wrong docker image? is that something with my tensorflow installation?

Comment: @Lescurel AFAIK that doesn't guarantee Tensorflow detecting the GPUs, am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, @doneforaiur

Comment: You can try this potential solution: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40874#issuecomment-651524235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still seems like the Docker container is not able to access the GPUs on the host machine even though you are passing --gpus all as an argument. A few things to try:

1. Make sure the Nvidia container toolkit is installed on the host - this is required for Docker to access Nvidia GPUs. You can install it with:

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add - \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

2. Pass additional runtime arguments to expose the GPUs:

```
--runtime=nvidia \
--gpus all \
-e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
```

3. Make sure the TensorFlow Docker image has GPU support
4. Double check GPU drivers are up-to-date on the host machine.

Some combination of these steps should allow the container to access the GPUs properly...

Answer (score 2):

tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu gets latest tensorflow version which is 2.13.0 (as of 07/08/23) and this tensorflow version requires cuda 11.8 which is not supported by your graphics card. You can see this logged in the error message

```
tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:266] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW
```

Check the latest cuda version supported by your graphics card and use the tensorflow version compatible with that cuda version: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

I am facing the same issue when I try to run tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu but tensorflow/tensorflow:2.4.3-gpu works. I have a slightly older gpu as you can see from the tensorflow version I am using.

Comment: I had to go to 2.10.1 to make it run on my 2080 ti. I checked several older versions of tensorflow, but not 2.10.*. Thanks!